# Find the North West and South East among bunch of Latitudes and Longitudes

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have bunch of location (Lat, Lng) data inside my database and let's assume it has the following columns:

> Resort
>
> Latitude
>
> Longitude

I would like to define the radius of available resorts and <strike>I need to find the place on North West and South East.</strike> <strike>**I need to find the most north-western resort and most south-eastern resort among those**</strike> my aim is draw a rectangle which contains all of the places.

What would be the algorithm for that?

The table is stored inside SQL Server and I can use SP or Function here. Also, C# code would be helpful as well.

**EDIT**

I need to find a place on NW and SE to determine the rectangle. I need to first sort this out. I am not looking for a way to find places within that rectangle for now.

**EDIT**

Here is my imagination for what I am after (sorry for the awful drawing):

[image]

think this as a world map and the blue circles are resorts. I need to find the lat and lng of two places which I mark with a brown circle.

**EDIT**

@Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out that I am on the wrong direction here. My aim is draw a rectangle which contains all of the places. And my question is telling another story.

Comment: From your comment to the first answer, are you saying you have Lat/longs for the resorts, but need to calculate lat/long for the place to search near?

Comment: Let's see if I got this straight. You have a bunch of resorts, you want to find the minimal circle that contains all of them (its radius is the radius you're looking for), and you want to find the most north-western resort and most south-eastern?

Comment: Maybe a picture of what you're after might help.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I was just doing that :) see the update.

Comment: @zmbq you got that straight. See the updated question with a picture.

Comment: If you draw a rectangle using those two points, you obviously exclude some of the most southerly resorts from that rectangle. Are you sure that's what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just realized that you are right. My aim is draw a rectangle which contains all of the places.

Comment: @tugberk - that's a very different problem - you may find that there are no actual resorts at any of the corners. You could start with a rectangle around one resort, then queue all other resorts. Dequeue each one, if it's not already covered by the rectangle, expand the rectangle as required to encompass it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever seems that I have a very ugly requirement here. Needs a lot of work on T-SQL part I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a rectangle where all the resorts fit inside here is the full example:

```
create table #testing (
Resort varchar(20),
Longitude int,
Latitude int
)

insert into #testing values ('Res 1', 10, 20)
insert into #testing values ('Res 2', -12, 30)
insert into #testing values ('Res 3', 3, -122)
insert into #testing values ('Res 4', 120, 120)
insert into #testing values ('Res 5', -2, 230)
insert into #testing values ('Res 6', 32, -2)

select
    min(Longitude) [Min Longitude],
    max(Longitude) [Max Longitude],
    min(Latitude) [Min Latitude],
    max(Latitude) [Max Latitude],
    convert(varchar, min(Longitude)) + "," + convert(varchar, max(Latitude)) [NW],
    convert(varchar, max(Longitude)) + "," + convert(varchar, min(Latitude)) [SE]
    from #testing

drop table #testing
```

Comment: thanks but you didn't get my question I think. I need to find a place on NW and SE to determine the rectangle. I need to first sort this out. Any idea how? So, `@Lat` and `@Lng` values are not there yet.

Comment: ohh, you need to, given a place, determinate the @Lat and @Lng?

Comment: @tugberk do you know all the latitudes and longitudes of all places?

Comment: yep, they are all stored inside the database. I need to find the most north-western resort and most south-eastern resort among those.

Comment: @tugberk what do you give preference, the North or the West? (imagine that you have a resort in the middle left of your picture, it's the most West but not the most North. Should I select that or should I select the most Left + the most Up existence even if they are from different resorts?)

Comment: my actual aim is that: draw a rectangle which contains all of the places. So, I need a coordinate on the nw and se. But it looks difficult. Is is possible? **Damien_The_Unbeliever** left some comment on my question above. They can be helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot. looks promising :) I am trying it out with my actual data now

Comment: Totally worked. I can't believe this is that simple. The cons of not knowing math very well. thanks!

Comment: you just sounded like Steve Ballmer: Develop, Develop, Develop! :D

Comment: It's a reasonable solution. Only really has issues if you're trying to find a rectangle around resorts that straddle 180° longitude east/west (because the max/min of longitude is an arbitrary line on the globe)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you please provide your solution as code? that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use a function that takes into account the curvature of the earth, which will make a reasonable difference if the distances are fairly large.

For example, you could create a function based on the [Haversine forumula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LatLong_HaversineDistanceMiles] (
@lat1 float,
@lon1 float,
@lat2 float,
@lon2 float
)
RETURNS float AS
BEGIN 

declare @dlon float
declare @dlat float
declare @a float
declare @c float
declare @d float

select @dlon=radians(@lon2)-radians(@lon1)
select @dlat=radians(@lat2)-radians(@lat1)

select @a =square(sin(@dlat/2.0)) + (cos(radians(@lat1)) * cos(radians(@lat2)) * square(sin(@dlon/2.0)))
select @c = 2.0 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1.0-@a))
select @d = 3956 * @c

return @d


end
```

You'd use it from a where clause to filter out those with a value > your radius.

Comment: thanks. Can you see my updated question? I think this logic wouldn't give me the a on NW and SE?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of resorts with their coordinates and you want a bounding "rectangle" for those resorts.

Then you need to issue two queries, one to find the minimum and maximum latitude, the other to find min and max longitude.

Then combine those values to get the correct corners.

**EDIT**
You can use SQL like this:

```
declare @minlat float, @maxlat float
select @minlat = min(latitude), @maxlat = max(latitude)
from resortstable
```

And similar for longitude. Then (@minlat, @minlong) is one corner and (@maxlat, @maxlong) the other. You might need to change those: I'm not sure whether latitude means N/S.

For the most NW resort you have a problem: what if one resort is the North-most and another the most West one? How are you going to choose?

**EDIT2**
Say you have only two resorts, one in the NE corner and the other the SW corner. Maybe add some more on a rough line between those two. What are the NW and SE corner-resorts now?

Comment: great approach and the problem is that I cannot imagine how to write the code for that on T-SQL. Any chance?

Comment: That will find the binding rectangle of your resorts. If you need a circle, it's the circle that contains this rectangle.

Note, however, that you might not have a resort in any of the corners, and you might not have a 'most south-eastern' resort. Say you have one resort 1 km to the north of the center, another 1 km to the east, another 1 km to the south and a last one 1km to the west. You have no most north-western resort, just a north one and a west one.